# SharePoint 2013 add a delete button to list view web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to add a delete button to a list view webpart and inserted the following code to a script editor web part. Unfortunately it is not working, so I will appreciate if you can help me correct the code.

```
< div > < button onclick = " DeleteItem ()" > Create the Item < /button></div >

 < div id = " output " > < /div>

var siteUrl="http://gowtham.sharepointmasters.com";

<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteListItem() {

    this.itemId = 10;

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    var List = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Gowtham');

    this.ListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);

    ListItem.deleteObject();


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(

        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),

        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)

    );

}


function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('List Item deleted: ' + itemId);

}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +

        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to add delete button to each item in the list view web part?

Answer (score 0):

How about use JSLink based on Edit(link to edit item) column?

A demo for your reference:
https://collab365.community/using-jslink-to-implement-delete-buttons-for-list-view/